# Error connecting to memsql with mysql J connector

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector, singlestore

I have memsql server version 6.7. I am able to connect to it using mysql java connector version 5.1.47 from my spring boot application.

But when i upgrade connector version to 8.0.16 I get below error - 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'performance_schema'

Ran query SHOW VARIABLES; on my memsql instance and I do not see system variable 'performance_schema'.

Can i change datasource.url string to ignore this variable? Any other latest version of driver is supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is the security issue in the 8.0.15 mysql driver you could use the mariaDb drivers instead.  We generally recommend folks use them with MemSQL:
https://docs.memsql.com/client-downloads/

MySQL 8 made a number of breaking changes (i.e., you will have issues with MySQL 8 drivers connecting to older versions of MySQL as well : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90994)

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17090:

> A relevant change in Spring Boot 2.1.5 would appear to be that it [upgraded MySQL's Java connector](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/81c2b1380b17bc31896e02a6fb12c8ca94692312) from 8.0.15 to **8.0.16**. The 8.0.x driver should be compatible with MySQL 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0 so this would either appear to be a problem with your configuration or, probably more likely, a **regression in the driver**. If you would like to pursue this, I would recommend asking for some help on the [MySQL forums](https://forums.mysql.com/index.php) and providing sufficient information to allow someone to reproduce the problem.

Try version 8.0.15 to see if that works better.

Comment: my issue is with using mysql connector with MEMSQL. mysql HAS a system variable called performance_schema by default but MEMSQL does not.

Comment: @user2456557 Seems the problem is that 8.0.16 requires performance_schema, while 8.0.15 doesn't, and since MEMSQL doesn't have one, it should work with 8.0.15, but not with 8.0.16. Since it's an easy thing to **test**, why not at least try?

Comment: i understand this but I do not want to try version 8.0.15 is because it has a vulnerability - https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-2692 which is only fixed in version 8.0.16

Comment: Vulnerability requires "high privileged attacker with logon to the infrastructure" and "human interaction from a person other than the attacker". If your environment is that vulnerable to begin with, you're really in trouble. At least try 8.0.15 to see if it works. That vulnerability shouldn't stop you.

Comment: 8.0.15 works but is vulnerable. The whole point of upgrade is to use dependencies with minimum vulnerabilities. At my workplace I do not determine which risks are acceptable or not.